# Django - ImportError: cannot import name

Tags: django, python-2.7, importerror, pythonpath, sys.path

I am having problem with 1 error, I installed all apps on Django 1.6.2 and Django 1.5.5 and having the same problem.

My settings are:

Django 1.5.5

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'polib',
    'easymode',
    'localeurl',
    'rosetta',
    'efc',
)
```

Django 1.6.2

```
INSTALLED_APPS += (
    "polib",
    "easymode",
    "localeurl",
    "rosetta",
    "efc",
)
```

And here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/efc/webapps/efc/lib/python2.7/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/efc/webapps/efc/lib/python2.7/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/efc/webapps/efc/lib/python2.7/django/core/management/base.py", line 242, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/home/efc/webapps/efc/lib/python2.7/django/core/management/base.py", line 284, in execute
    self.validate()
  File "/home/efc/webapps/efc/lib/python2.7/django/core/management/base.py", line 310, in validate
    num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
  File "/home/efc/webapps/efc/lib/python2.7/django/core/management/validation.py", line 34, in get_validation_errors
    for (app_name, error) in get_app_errors().items():
  File "/home/efc/webapps/efc/lib/python2.7/django/db/models/loading.py", line 196, in get_app_errors
    self._populate()
  File "/home/efc/webapps/efc/lib/python2.7/django/db/models/loading.py", line 78, in _populate
    self.load_app(app_name)
  File "/home/efc/webapps/efc/lib/python2.7/django/db/models/loading.py", line 99, in load_app
    models = import_module('%s.models' % app_name)
  File "/home/efc/webapps/efc/lib/python2.7/django/utils/importlib.py", line 40, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/efc/webapps/efc/myproject/efc/models.py", line 4, in <module>
    from easymode.i18n.decorators import I18n
  File "/home/efc/lib/python2.7/easymode/i18n/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    import easymode.i18n.gettext
  File "/home/efc/lib/python2.7/easymode/i18n/gettext.py", line 24, in <module>
    from easymode.utils import polibext
  File "/home/efc/lib/python2.7/easymode/utils/polibext.py", line 11, in <module>
    from rosetta import polib
ImportError: cannot import name polib
```

The last line in the 'polibext.py' line 11 is:

```
if 'rosetta' in settings.INSTALLED_APPS:
    from rosetta import polib
else:
    try:
        import polib
    except ImportError:
        raise ImproperlyConfigured(
            """
            Please install either django-rosetta: 
            http://code.google.com/p/django-rosetta/
            or polib:
            http://bitbucket.org/izi/polib/src/
            otherwise easymode.utils.polibext won't work"""
        )
```

I installed both. Still having the error.

Can you please help?

Thanks

Comment: if you perform the command `import rosetta` or `import polib` in the console - what do you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

As rentgeeen has found out, the problem was with django-rosetta 0.7.4 version. See his comment below.

---

Looks like you don't have django-rosetta installed. Run

```
pip install django-rosetta
```

from the console.  That should install django-rosetta and it's dependedcies (six, requests and polib).

In the remote chance that you have django-rosetta installed, but not polib, run

```
pip install polib
```

As a sidenote, you might wanna look into virtualenv tutorials (for Webfaction or otherwise: http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2013/09/14/django-in-virtualenv-on-webfactions-apache-with-mod-wsgi/) If you plan on having several python projects on your account, I'd strongly advise it.

Comment: Hello, thanks for reply they are installed and also in the sys path and httpd.conf: https://www.dropbox.com/s/3diyo8lpw5zm8t0/Screenshot%202014-03-22%2011.30.45.png https://www.dropbox.com/s/dhy95xlevcbqizi/Screenshot%202014-03-22%2011.31.18.png, still dont know why still having the error.

Comment: Problem was django-rosetta 0.7.4, I installed 0.7.0 and it works now :) Weird bug. I am going to install 0.7.3 if that has a bug or something...